# Laravel - use multiple value in where DB query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

in my `posts` table have `extra_category` column with saved mutiple value(json) same `["12","15","23"]` now I want use this value in DB query for get category name for each value .

my Controller:

```
$excatname = DB::table('categories')
               ->where('id', '=', $post->extra_category)->get();
                   view()->share('excatname', $excatname);
```

and my view:

```
    @foreach($excatname as $excatnamez)
      {{ $excatnamez->name }}
    @endforeach
```

but get error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (SQL: select * from `categories` where `id` = 12)
```

Note: when `extra_categoy` have single value for ex : `15`  worked as well.
cast is defined on the model
`protected $casts = ['extra_category' => 'array',]`

Comment: The proper solution is don't store arrays in a database column, use a proper relationship (many-to-many pivot table for example). Beyond that, did you try `whereIn()` instead? (After converting your string representation of an array to an actual array that is...)

Comment: `$excatname = DB::table('categories')->whereIn('id', '=', [$post->extra_category])->get();` when use it get error : Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/faqpin/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 962

Comment: `whereIn('id', $post->extra_category)`, only 2 parameters, but you'd need to convert `$post->extra_category` to an array... Wrapping it in `[ ... ]` doesn't do that though...

Comment: @TimLewis how convert `$post->extra_category` to an array. can you help me.thank you

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head; do some searching on how to convert a string representation of an array to an actual array in PHP. I'm sure that's not that difficult of a task to do...

Comment: yes you right, if I two parameters is same string, for example if `id` same `extra_categroy` was string, do I still have to convert an array? or I can use `whereJsonContains` ?

Comment: I agree with Tim that is really a bad design it would very helpful for you if you can redesign it. If you have stored array in db as string then on application level you can use `json_decode()` to convert back into array [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce3f07006b665270e60dbbc8197a137ae56dc707)